# creating .htaccess to cache images

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use `.htaccess`  file to return image if exists or call generators if not exists.

example :

```
img src="images/myimage1.jpg"
```

If `myimage1.jpg` not exists, it generates it calling `createThumb.php?image=myimage1.jpg` after that it returnS.

please help creating this `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule image/(.+)$ createThumb.php?image=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
# Check if a JPG file doesn't exist.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1.jpg !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /createThumb.php?image=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And then inside your createThumb.php you can create the image and store in %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images folder and return proper MIME type response to browser for this image after image creation.